# Finding the closest datetimes in 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have 2 lists (examples below, but real one has 100+ in each list):

```
ListA = [29/11/2017 03:44:42, 23/11/2017 07:36:35, etc....]
ListB = [12/09/2017 02:00:34, 12/05/2017 14:00:25, etc....]
```

I'm trying to go through every element in `ListA` and find out which element in `ListB` is closest to that date. I'm struggling to do so though.

I first made sure both lists elements are datetime objects.

But after this, I keep coming up stuck... I'm probably thinking about this wrong.

```
for i in ListA:
    closestTimestamp = min(key, key=lambda datetime: abs(timestamp - [j for j in ListB]))
```

It's saying `key` is not defined. I'm very new to Python to apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: If you can sort both date lists, you can use `np.searchsorted`, which should be O(NLogN).

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an *iterable* (e.g. `ListB`) and a key function to [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min). Try this:

```
for a in ListA:
    closestTimestamp = min(listB, key=lambda b: abs(a-b))
```

BTW, the time complexity of this solution is `O(nm)`, which may be slow for bigger lists. In that case consider using [binary search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) for `O(nlogm)` complexity.